# K6 Load Testing - I am completely baffled by the stats that are printed at the end

Tags: k6

Here is my very simple K6 script that I am running:

```
import {group } from "k6";
import { Trend} from "k6/metrics";
let response = null;
let loginTime = new Trend('login_time');
import http from "k6/http";

export let options = {
  stages: [
        {iterations: 1}
  ]
};

export default function(){

  group("Log In", function(){
    let url = "myurl";
    let headers = {
          headers: {
            "accept": "*/*",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "connection": "keep-alive"
          }
    };
    
    response = http.get(url,headers);

    loginTime.add(response.timings.duration);
    console.log("The duration for this request was:" + response.timings.duration);
})
};
```

The script just sends one request and runs for one interation and I save the duration of this request to a Trend called 'login_time'.

The stats that K6 prints at the end are as follows:

```
data_received..............: 29 kB  9.0 kB/s
    data_sent..................: 3.4 kB 1.1 kB/s
    group_duration.............: avg=3.15s      min=3.15s      med=3.15s      max=3.15s      p(90)=3.15s      p(95)=3.15s
    http_req_blocked...........: avg=414.88ms   min=2µs        med=291.79ms   max=1.31s      p(90)=976.28ms   p(95)=1.14s
    http_req_connecting........: avg=17.55ms    min=0s         med=25.97ms    max=31.96ms    p(90)=31.1ms     p(95)=31.53ms
    http_req_duration..........: avg=216.66ms   min=29.72ms    med=231.06ms   max=478.72ms   p(90)=407.62ms   p(95)=443.17ms
    http_req_receiving.........: avg=407.68µs   min=119.9µs    med=205.8µs    max=1.33ms     p(90)=892.84µs   p(95)=1.11ms
    http_req_sending...........: avg=74.86µs    min=12.4µs     med=76.8µs     max=170.2µs    p(90)=142.79µs   p(95)=156.49µs
    http_req_tls_handshaking...: avg=102.44ms   min=0s         med=73.61ms    max=315.35ms   p(90)=238.5ms    p(95)=276.93ms
    http_req_waiting...........: avg=216.18ms   min=29.59ms    med=230.68ms   max=477.3ms    p(90)=406.68ms   p(95)=441.99ms
    http_reqs..................: 5      1.563597/s
    iteration_duration.........: avg=3.15s      min=3.15s      med=3.15s      max=3.15s      p(90)=3.15s      p(95)=3.15s
    iterations.................: 1      0.312719/s
    login_time.................: avg=478.721924 min=478.721924 med=478.721924 max=478.721924 p(90)=478.721924 p(95)=478.721924
    vus........................: 1      min=1 max=1
    vus_max....................: 1      min=1 max=1
```

As you can see all the stats for my custom Trend 'login_time' show the same number 478.721924.

'login_time' is recording the 'response.timings.duration' - duration here is supposed to be 'http_req_duration'.

So I would expect the stats on the 'http_req_duration' row to be exactly the same as the 'login_time' stats i.e. all show 478.721924.

Instead the stats on the 'http_req_duration' row are completely different and all show different numbers even though only 1 iteration was ran so they should all be the same. (Only the 'max' values shows 478.72).

As only 1 iteration was ran - the data in each column for each row should be the same.

So my question is, can I trust any of these numbers and if so which ones?

Also, I want to report how long login took - is this just the http_req_duration value or do I have to include other values like http_req_blocked....or is that just waiting for K6 getting ready to send the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are doing multiple requests, probably because you have redirects, common in login scenarios.

This is why http_req_* metrics have multiple values because `http_reqs`(the number of requests done) is 5. So you have 5 sets of the `http_req_*`.

`http_req_duration` is the sum of all others so this is most probably what you want, and you can read about the [others in the documentation](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/metrics#http-specific-built-in-metrics), but in general, if you need them you will know ;).

But res.timings has only the *last* response timings, so you might need to time it with Date as in

```js
var start = Date.now();
// do something
var took = Date.now() - start;
```

Or you can use a group around the request and its duration.

Comment: Great answer...makes perfect sense now. Thanks Михаил Стойков